# Cannot login via ssh into CentOs machine after setting ulimit for open files to unlimited

Tags: ssh, centos6, ulimit

I have set ulimit for open files on my centos machine by editing `/etc/security/limits.conf` post which I am unable to login into the machine.

This was the change made in /etc/security/limits.conf file.

- - nofiles unlimited

A tail of verbose output of my ssh login is as follows.

```
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eow
debug2: channel 0: close_read
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: close_write
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 fd -1/-1 cfd -1)

debug3: channel 0: close_fds r -1 w -1 e 6 c -1
debug3: Wrote 32 bytes for a total of 2229
debug3: Wrote 64 bytes for a total of 2293
Connection to 172.16.47.108 closed.
Transferred: sent 2096, received 2528 bytes, in 0.0 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 91488.9, received 110345.4
debug1: Exit status 254
```

A ping to the machine works fine and give back replies. Then why is my ssh connection getting terminated.

Comment: Use `ssh -vvv` and add this to your question.

Comment: Added the output.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/577437/what-is-the-impact-of-increasing-nofile-limits-in-etc-security-limits-conf

Comment: The first thing I would do is to revert the changed configuration file. When making such changes I always keep a root login open - just in case. If you did not leave a root login open you may need to find another way to log in to the server either locally or through a serial link. If all else fails I would boot a rescue system. Once the config file has been reverted I will look at what the logs on the server say about the problem.